# Retrieving count of column mySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

Hey guys I have a mysql table called interests with 4 columns. interestID, name,  categoryID interest_desc and date. the categoryID column is linked to a seperate table. How would I use a mysql query that checked how many interests are in a certain category?

Im guessing i use some sort of count() query?

Thanks guys

Update -

```
$count_query_v1 = "SELECT categoryID, COUNT(*) AS total FROM interests GROUP by categoryID; ";     $answer = mysql_query($count_query_v1) or die(mysql_error()); echo $answer;
```

Getting closer but still not perfect, i want to echo out the categoryID with the most interestID's

Answer (score 2):

```
select category_name, count(*) as total
from interests i left join category c on c.category_id = i.category_id
group by i.category_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

count + group by,
assuming interestID is the unique primary key,
and each interest is tied to single category (as what you have shown)

```
select categoryID, count(*) as total
from interests
group by categoryID;

// the above example is a simple group by ID without using inner join
```

output :-

```
categoryID, total
```

Comment: Trying to print out the categoryID and the total interests

$count_query_v1 = "SELECT categoryID, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM interests
GROUP by categoryID;
";

$answer = mysql_query($count_query_v1) or die(mysql_error());
echo $answer;

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(interestID) FROM interests WHERE categoryID = 'yourvalue';

SELECT COUNT(interestID), categoryID FROM interests GROUP BY categoryID;

Comment: how would i go about echoing the category with the most interestsID's

Comment: You want to echo : the number,the name of the category, with categoryID belonging to another table let's say category?

Comment: I want to get the category with the most interestID's in it

Comment: SELECT MAX(COUNT(interestID)), categoryID FROM interests GROUP BY categoryID;

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using the insert query each query will insert one record, so just count the number of insert queries you run by using a counter varialble.